# C# unable to create table with tinytext

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am using the code below to try to create a table. However it is giving me an error message "Cannot find data type TINYTEXT". I'm using SQLite, VS2017.  The SQLite docs says TINYTEXT is a type, and should be accepted. Anyone have info on why this isn't working, what needs to be changed?

Thanks

```
         DBResult dbResult = new DBResult();

            SqlConnection dbConnect = new SqlConnection("Server =localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;");

            string query = @"CREATE TABLE test.task (
            TaskID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            ParentID INTEGER,
            Title TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
            Notes MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
            Priority SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT NULL,
            )";


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnect);
            try
            {
                dbConnect.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbResult.isSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                dbResult.isSuccess = false;
                dbResult.result = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnect.Close();
            }
            return dbResult;
        }
```

Comment: Your connection string doesn't look like you're using SQLite?

Comment: Your connection string shows you are using SQL Server Express instance and not SQLLite

Comment: I Agreed with @sticky bit

Comment: Before I answer is it MySql, Sqlite or Sql Server. TINYTEXT is from MySql. You say you are using Sqlite. Your code is using the Sql Server provider. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Put an Sqlite connection:
using System.Data.SQLite;

```
SQLiteConnection dbConnect = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=PATH_TO_SQLITE_FILE;FailIfMissing=True;");
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're using to craft your query is not describing the syntax used by the database to which you are connecting.

Basically, it looks like you have referred to documentation for MySQL, but you are connecting to a Microsoft SQL database which uses Transact-SQL commands. There are many different types of database which may have varying features and different ways of constructing queries.

VARCHAR is part of the ISO SQL:2003 standard; The TEXT data types, including TINYTEXT, are non-standard. Therefore, you would need to adjust your query to something like this:

```
string query = @"CREATE TABLE test.task (
        TaskID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        ParentID INTEGER,
        Title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        Notes VARCHAR(65532) DEFAULT NULL,
        Priority SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT NULL,
        )";
```